# Having a std::map not order

Tags: c++, json, header, stdmap

I am using a header-only json library and it uses a `std::map`. I would prefer although to have it not be ordered.

https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/src/json.hpp#L371

There is the snippet that I'm wondering if I can fix. Assuming "ObjectType" is a `std::map`. Is there any way to remove the order from it or somehow make the `std::less<StringType>` irrelevant.

It seems that changing the source to support `std::unordered_map` would be too large of a task to be worth it.

Comment: What advantage do you hope to get from having the map not be ordered?

Comment: You want to change `std::map` to behave as `std::unordered_map`? If that was possible then `std::unordered_map` wouldn't exist... Well anyway, without changing the actual source code, no takesy-backsies...

Comment: Please read what a [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is.  Note -- *std::map is a sorted associative container...*.

Comment: Maintaining order is an integral property of underlying data structure, which ensures relatively quick access. Without order it would be slower than simple array of pairs *key, value*.

Comment: The advantage is maintaining original order of the json data.

Comment: Is there no way to fake ordering by ordering the elements based on index?

Comment: wanted to ask same.. what if you would store _records_ in map, not strings.. and define own ordering method, based on original order. Modyifying library to use unordered_map is possible, though some code may be built based on assumption of ordered elements? Or store indexes of elements..

Comment: @MaxKunes: If you want order based on insertion order, use `std::vector`.

Comment: Short answer is no.  Based on the code you linked, you would have to some pretty heavy lifting to pull that std::map usage out and replace with something that preserves insertion order like a vector.  Most JSON libraries I have worked with also do not preserve order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `std::unordered_map` is not a viable solution here, since it will not preserve the insertion order either. "Unordered" here means pretty much ignorant to any ordering whatsoever.

Instead for your particular task you want to somehow save the original insertion order, so here are some options:

- change `std::map` key to the index number or replace `std::map` with `std::vector`. The latter actually makes sense even if you want to retain the ability to search by the object name, as JSON objects don't tend to get too big so linear search probably won't introduce any noticeable drawback.
- find a way to store the desired ordering separately. `std::vector` of keys can handle the storage, and you can add some iterator trickery to make your container cycle over the preferred order, e.g. by overloading `begin()` and `end()` methods.
- use a multiple-keyed map as a ready solution - [boost::multiindex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) is a default choice.

Comment: I agree that a std::vector could accomplish although the issue occurs when trying to translate somewhere up to 10000 lines of code to support it.